# Was Leonard Hofstadter's character inspired from George Costanza's character?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory, seinfeld

I have already seen *The Big Bang Theory* TV series and now I am watching *Seinfeld*. By looking at George Costanza's character I can relate too many similarities between Leonard and him, let alone their physical appearance.

So did they have any common writer or something? Or is this a coincidence?

Answer (score 6):

I highly doubt it.  Aside from some physical similarities (glasses and squinting eyes) I haven't found them similar at all.

Leonard and Sheldon are named (but maybe not character insipred?) after Nobel Prize winners Robert Hofstadter (1961 in Physics with one other scientist) and Leon Cooper (1972 in Physics with two other scientists).

Comment: Sheldon was originally slated to be named Kenny when the show was being developed as "Lenny, Penny and Kenny" :)

Answer (score 4):

Well there are enough similarities between Seinfeld and The Bing Bang Theories that somebody already has compared them.

https://suggestsmagic.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/big-bang-theory-is-a-seinfeld-copycat/

Both George and Leonard share more features that just the looks: they both are obsessive, specially with details, not confident about themselves, they both get frustrated quite fast, had issues keeping steady relationships, even certain body language gestures are quite similar.

But to be honest there is no way to know if someone borrowed George features and characteristics in order to create Leonard, even if the writers were asked because they will never accept it if it was the case.

Comment: He might have “George” like character traits but in terms of relationship dynamics, Leonard is the Seinfeld of the group, Sheldon is Kramer, Howard/Raj is George (sometimes Newman) and Penny is Elaine, it’s the same character format. Oddball, Nitwit, female perspective and the standard lamp shading straight man.